# computing one's Erdös-Bacon-Sabbath number

Tags: bands

[Erdös numbers](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/37902/figures-of-merit-erd%C5%91s-number-in-resume-cv), Erdös-Bacon numbers, and [Erdös-Bacon-Sabbath](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/blog/whats-your-erdos-bacon-sabbath-number) numbers are not uncommonly found on a CV these days.  It's easy to find lists and online tools to discover low values for the first two, but not for the last.

Are there lists of musician-collaborators with the band Black Sabbath that were not themselves in the band -- corresponding to an Erdös number of 1, not 0?  (Googling for that gets swamped by *covers* of their songs recorded by other bands.)

Or must one resort to individually contacting all of one's own musician-collaborators?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any online tools to calculate academic collaboration distance (i.e. a generalisation of the Erdős number)?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/13120/are-there-any-online-tools-to-calculate-academic-collaboration-distance-i-e-a)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a Sabbath calculator at http://static.echonest.com/SixDegreesOfBlackSabbath/index.html

An Erdös calculator at http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/collaborationDistance.html

& Google can do Bacon numbers right in the search line

*I have a vague claim to a Bacon number of 3, a Sabbath number of 2 [neither documented, hence vague & unsupported] - though have never written a mathematical paper in my life, so my Erdös will forever remain **∞** ;-)*